Choosing Between a Small Cluster and a Workstation for MD Simulations and Quantum Chemistry Calculations
I am part of a research group and we are in the process of deciding on a computing resource for our simulation and data analysis needs.
Our primary tasks include:molecular Dynamics (MD) simulations (both coarse-grained and full atomistic), stochastic simulations and small Quantum Chemistry calculations (QM-MD, and structure calculations at DFT-HF level, rarely MP2 or CI).
We work on different simulation timescales, from small systems treated in full quantum mechanics detail to larger systems treated classically through MD simulations (up to the size of the proteasome). MD simulations can generate files up to 10 GB in size per run, which we need to analyze subsequently.
Given these requirements, we are considering either purchasing a small GPU cluster or a high-performance workstation. We need a versatile computing resource that can handle both simulations and data analysis. Here are some specific points we are contemplating:

MD Simulations: We know that GPU clusters are highly efficient for MD simulations. How significant is the performance difference between a GPU cluster and a high-performance workstation for these tasks?
Quantum Chemistry Calculations: How well do GPU clusters handle quantum chemistry calculations (ORCA and GAMESS, mainly, maybe some implementation in python of our own but that's much more unlikely) compared to a CPU-based workstation?
Data Analysis: Considering the heavy data output (on average 10 GB per run), is a workstation sufficient for efficient data analysis, or would a cluster be more beneficial?
Versatility: Given the need to balance between simulations and data analysis, which option (GPU cluster vs. workstation) offers better overall versatility for our mixed workload?

Could you please provide some guidance or share experiences on which option might be more suitable for our needs?

It seems that a workstation fits what you want to do. If so, I suggest you reading this discussion: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/7151/suggestions-on-personal-computers-for-matter-modeling :)

10GB seems to be pretty small to me; In condensed matter research we easily go much bigger. If you are only ever going to do molecules, you do not need to get much more fancy equipment. If you are buying a computer soon, do beware that rumours are all over the place that Intel is really suffering in the market and are overheating their chips, leading to quick damages. You should check if your desired computing packages can even use GPU or not.

@naturallyInconsistent Thanks for the feedback, I am sure that GROMACS is well supported for GPU-acceleration and 10 GB were effectively a gross underestimation for  simulations (I was mislead by my last project that was fairly small in dimensionality). We work mainly with "large" biomolecules where large means essentially the proteasome to us. We also work on aggregation properties, so probably for peptides and such we will need to simulate 50+ proteins/peptides/whatever. This is the motivation for our interest in a fixed workstation.

Are you suggesting that you would be buying/building a computer cluster yourself, as opposed to applying for time on an existing cluster?

@isolatedmatrix  we would like to have an independent workstation/small cluster for small to medium sized simulations ( the biggest thing we would simulate on such workstatiion would be the aggregation of peptides and maybe proteasome, so not extremely large systems but surely not the smallest either). Obviously, i think that buying time on an existing cluster would be much easier and time effective, but we are looking to have our own stuff going on while applying for computational time for bigger occasional problems.

Go for gaming PCs. Especially if you are using GROMACS. You'll get significantly
more performance out of RTX40NN GPUs and 13th/14th gen. Intel i7s than you will out of pre-built workstations,
and you can get these machines a lot cheaper than the pre-built workstations. Furthermore, a lot of workstations
place emphasis on hardware capabilities that you can't make use of while doing MD (e.g. T-series GPUs).
A few of the groups I have worked in previously have all their machines linked together in the local network,
which allows the group members to run jobs on other people's machines while they are not using theirs.
I think installing and managing a SLURM (or equivalent) workload manager on a system like this could
be easier than running and maintaining a cluster. From a purely logistical point of view it's also safer: If someone borks the cluster, then you're in for an unscheduled holiday (assuming you're not the sysadmin).
Finally: Most MD analysis code doesn't really scale well, and I'm not aware of any MD analysis tools that make use
of GPUs. Maybe some exist, but at the moment you'd be better served by a set of PCs than a single cluster.

Do consider the recent stories about instabilities and degradation of 13th/14th gen Intel processors before buying. Intel have very recently started rolling out an update that they say will fix it, but I think the jury is still out on whether it fully fixes the issue or not.

I will probably opt for Amd Threadripper, I've got your same feeling about intel processors
